# Disconnection from a FTP server in python with the librabry pyftpdlib

Tags: python, server, ftp

I would like to know if there is a way to translate in python the fact that someone disconnet from my ftp server with pyftplib. I know that there is a function call 'on_logout' but i don't know how to use it.

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

Create your own implementation of [`FTPHandler`](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.handlers.FTPHandler) and use it with your server instance.

Though the `on_logout` is triggered in a response to user explicitly logging out. But most FTP clients do not do that, they simply disconnect. For that, use [`on_disconnect`](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.handlers.FTPHandler.on_disconnect).

```
class MyFTPHandler(FTPHandler):
    def on_logout(self, username):
        print("%s logged out" % username)

    def on_disconnect():
        print("disconnected")

handler = MyFTPHandler
# ...
server = FTPServer(('', 21), handler)
```